# Very slow wifi Broadcom BCM4352 Ubuntu 16.04 Dell XPS15

Tags: 16.04, wireless, broadcom

After installing Ubuntu 16.04.1LTS on my Dell XPS15 with a Broadcom BCM4352 [1028:0019], I'm experiencing extremely slow wifi throughput (1-2 Mb/s tested via fast.com and `iperf` vs another machine on the LAN). I've verified that this is specific to this machine and that other machines on the network are getting the full throughput I'd expect. Out of the box the wifi didn't work at all and I installed the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package which at least got the wifi up.

Relevant section from `lspci` follows:

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
Subsystem: Dell BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0019]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
Memory at f7a00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [68] Vendor Specific Information: Len=44 <?>
Capabilities: [ac] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [13c] Device Serial Number c4-8e-00-ff-ff-00-00-01
Capabilities: [150] Power Budgeting <?>
Capabilities: [160] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [1b0] Latency Tolerance Reporting
Capabilities: [220] #15
Kernel driver in use: wl
Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

I've run the `wifi-information` script and dropped the results into a gist: https://gist.github.com/tgross/4c930001dc3bc128eb703e880e395a34. Blacklists look correct as I expect them from that output. `dmesg` has this oddball for which I haven't found anything useful for in Google yet:

```
$ dmesg | grep wl
[   13.676176] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[   13.676179] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   13.678254] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   13.680068] wl 0000:06:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
```

Another possible clue: my Verizon FiOS router is dual-network; it has a 2.4GHz and a 5GHz network both on the same SSID. This machine is the only machine on the 2.4GHz network. From the output of the `wifi-information` script, I can see that I'm seeing my neighbors' 5GHz networks but not my own.

Comment: The `ifconfig` result shows me `MTU 1500`. This is too large for Wireless, and causes fragmentation (you send 2 packets for every 1 packet you try to send). Install `tracepath` (`sudo apt install tracepath`, `man tracepath`) to determine your optimim `MTU`. Note: to change `MTU` you must take the NIC down and up.

Comment: I think the MTU *may* be too high, but not that it *IS* too high. Mine is set on 1500 and yet my fast.com yields 330 Mbps. Test first.

Comment: I don't think it's MTU.  `tracepath -n example.com` shows pmtu of 1500, and with `-l 1500` there's no pmtu shown. `ping -M do -s 1472 example.com` succeeds (leaving 28 bytes for the headers, 1473 byte packets fail as expected). The other devices on the 5GHz network are also using 1500MTU without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I've figured it out. I found a post on the Dell support forums where someone was showing that they were getting `801.11abg` only and not `n` despite having an `802.11n`-capable router. [This comment](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/os-applications/f/4613/p/19628926/20812387#20812387) suggested checking router settings that might be not-quite-persnickety-enough.

In my Verizon FiOS router there's a compatibility mode setting, which, when toggled to strict `802.11n` "performance mode" is now allowing me to get the full expected throughput on my connection.

[screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i544W.png)

Thanks for the debugging assistance though @waltinator and @chili555